# Assign Macro to Command Button Fail

Tags: vba, excel

I have written a macro which is working smoothly for approximately 1,000 rows when I run it in the Developer but when I link it to a command button and start it by pressing the button it is just executing it for one row.

Does someone know what is going wrong here and how to solve this issue? Thanks :)

```
Sub AutomaticallyCalculateted()

Dim lastrow As Long

lastrow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(8).Row


Tabelle3.Range("O9:O" & lastrow).FormulaLocal = "=WENN(ODER(K9="""";L9="""");"""";WENNFEHLER((L9-K9)/K9;""""))"


Tabelle3.Range("P9:P" & lastrow).FormulaLocal = "=WENN(ODER(L9="""";M9="""");"""";WENNFEHLER((M9-L9)/L9;""""))"


Tabelle3.Range("Q9:Q" & lastrow).FormulaLocal = "=WENN(ODER(M9="""";N9="""");"""";WENNFEHLER((N9-M9)/M9;""""))"

End Sub
```

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: When you press the button, is the _active_ sheet the one you think it should be?

Comment: Your lastRow is being defined off the ActiveSheet, but your formula are going into Tabelle3

Comment: @Nathan_Sav you are right. This one was to obvious! Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your lastRow is being defined off the ActiveSheet, but your formula are going into Tabelle3